# Does 'option accept-invalid-http-response' work in HAProxy 1.7.12?

Tags: haproxy

The server I am connecting to is returning what looks like an invalid Date header and I want HAProxy to ignore the error.

Unfortunately I have no control over the server, I am using a third party tool.

I have tried 'option accept-invalid-http-response' in both the backend and defaults sections, with the same result.

The invalid header isn't being ignored,
my client always gets a '502 Bad Gateway' response.

From 'shows errors'

```
[21/Dec/2020:14:40:59.197] backend <BACKEND> (#3): invalid response
  frontend <FRONTEND> (#2), server <SERVER> (#1), event #5
  src <IP>:46508, session #6, session flags 0x0000008e
  HTTP msg state MSG_RQBEFORE(0), msg flags 0x00000000, tx flags 0x08600000
  HTTP chunk len 0 bytes, HTTP body len 0 bytes
  buffer flags 0x80008021, out 0 bytes, total 50 bytes
  pending 50 bytes, wrapping at 16384, error at position 50:
  00000  HTTP/1.1 204 OK\r\n
  00017  Date: Mon Dec 2020 14:40:58 GMT\r\n
```

Or maybe there is something else wrong with the response header.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try to set "tune.bufsize 32768" in global section of haproxy configuration?

Comment: @GagaSamushia Yes I could, but why? The response is less than 100 bytes. I did try bumping "tune.http.maxhdr 500" but that produced the same results.

Comment: The documentation for the option only mentions invalid header names. Are you sure it is expected to help in your case? But also does HAProxy even care about the date format? From the 'show errors' output I would be suspecting that your server may be forgetting to send the empty line after headers at the end of a 204 response. Could you verify that?

Comment: @MichałPolitowski Yes, I have verified that the server is NOT sending the empty line after the headers. Thanks for pointing out that the doc says the option is restricted to `header names`, I didn't catch that on the first 3 or 4 readings.